# Kernel panic-not syncing: no init found

Tags: boot, init

When I try to boot up my custom linux from scratch it mounts the root filesystem then I get this message: `Kernel panic-not syncing: no init found.` I have the init compiled from source and I have the necessary libraries to run init. What did I do wrong?

Comment: *Where* do you have `init`, *how* do you boot your system? *What* is the kernel commandline, *what* are defaults you changed in the kernel? Are you using a normal root or using some `initrd` thing to mount a temporary root before mounting the real one? As the kernel quite simply says, `no init found`. No need to complicate, it cannot find init. Is that the only error message or is that preceded by more errors?

Comment: Are you *sure* it mounted the root filesystem? Try passing `init=/bin/sh` or similar on the kernel command line. See if that works (should land you with a shell).

Comment: Are you sure that the root filesystem is mounted? Are you sure that your init works on that kernel? There's far too little information in your question to help you. What is your processor architecture? How did you configure your kernel? Where and what is your root filesystem? What's your init program and how did you compile and install it?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says, you have no init program. Your initramfs should have an /sbin/init that starts all userland processes.

Comment: actually I have an init file ready

Comment: @gabemai, do you use an initramfs? If so, how is it populated? You can check its contents with `zcat /boot/initramfs-3.8.0-rc4.img | cpio -itv`

Comment: @Dennis, you are assuming the OP is using an `initramfs`? Why? Is this an issue that is specific to `initramfs`'es? I don't think so, I'd say whatever gets mounted as the root filesystem (possibly the real root unless someone actually does use `initramfs`es) does not have `/bin/init`.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think running without initramfs was possible these days as you'd need a minimal /dev and /sbin/init. Guess I was wrong :)